# How to check if app is running in Xcode simulator from mac terminal?

Tags: xcode, bash, macos, shell, ios-simulator

For purposes of setting up automated e2e tests on a local machine I need to be able to check whether my app has launched in the xcode simulator in a bash script. How would I do this?